# How do I specify the name of a JAXB element using Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, annotations, abstract-class

I have a situation in which a Java object contains a generic `Payload<T>` that needs to be marshalled into xml.  So given the following classes:

**AbstractBox**

```
@XmlTransient
public abstract class AbstractBox {
    String type = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    String name = this.getClass().getCanonicalName();

    // setters/getters snipped

    public abstract String saySomething();
}
```

**SmallBox**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="small-box")
@XmlType(name="small-box")
public class SmallBox extends AbstractBox {

    @XmlElement
    public String getMsg() {
        return saySomething();
    }
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public String saySomething() {
        return "I'm a small box";
    }
}
```

**Payload**

```
@XmlTransient
public class Payload<T> {
    private T payload;

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

and some code like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class JaxbAnnotationsTest<P>
{
    String name;
    int age;
    int id;
    Payload<P> payload;

    // setters and getters snipped

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JaxbAnnotationsTest<AbstractBox> example = new JaxbAnnotationsTest<AbstractBox>();
        example.setName("Brion");
        example.setId(100);
        example.setAge(34);
        Payload<AbstractBox> object = new Payload<AbstractBox>();
        object.setPayload(new SmallBox());
        example.setPayloadContainer(object);

        try {
            XmlMapper xmapper = new XmlMapper();
            xmapper.writeValue(System.out, example);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Damn..." + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I expect to see:

```xml
<JaxbAnnotationsTest>
  <name>Brion</name>
  <age>34</age>
  <id>100</id>
  <payloadContainer>
    <small-box>
      <type>SmallBox</type>
      <name>sandbox.xml.jaxb.annotations.SmallBox</name>
      <msg>I'm a small box</msg>
    </small-box>
  </payloadContainer>
</JaxbAnnotationsTest>
```

but instead I get:

```xml
<JaxbAnnotationsTest>
  <name>Brion</name>
  <age>34</age>
  <id>100</id>
  <payloadContainer>
    <payload>
      <type>SmallBox</type>
      <name>sandbox.xml.jaxb.annotations.SmallBox</name>
      <msg>I'm a small box</msg>
    </payload>
  </payloadContainer>
</JaxbAnnotationsTest>
```

I've tried using `@XmlType` on the concrete subclass to change `payload` to `small-box` but that didn't work either.  If I remove the `Payload<P>` object and simply have a class member  `payload` of generic type P then the `paymentContainer` tag goes away, but `payload` remains and does not use the `small-box` name I've specified.

Is there a way for me to force JAXB (any implementation) to set the tag to the name specified in the subclass instead of the generic type property?

**Update:**
The selected answer provides the solution but I wanted to follow up in the question as well. My problem was two-fold:

1. I was using `@XmlTransient` on the `Payload<T>` class and needed to instead use an `@XmlAnyElement` annotation on the `setPayload(T payload)` method (though I suspect it doesn't matter which method of the setter/getter pair is annotated as long as only one has the annotation).
2. I was using Jackson 2's `JacksonJaxbXmlProvider` which is an incomplete JAXB implementation that was ignoring the `@XmlRootElement` of the element used as the value of the `@XmlAnyElement`-annotated property.

Changing my JAXB provider to use the Java 6/7 built-in JAXB provider generated the output I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Payload` class expects any bean type as a property, so JAXB doesn't know how to marshall  that particular object (in this case `SmallBox`). Since you need to keep the generic property in Payload the solution should be

1. Remove `@XmlTransient` annotation to make these types available for marshalling (I am wondering how it worked with this annotation as you mentioned)
2. Annotate `setPayload` in `Payload` class with `@XmlAnyElement` as follows

public class Payload {
    private T payload;

```
public T getPayload() {
    return payload;
}

@XmlAnyElement
public void setPayload(T payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}
```

}

`@XmlAnyElement` javadoc says

> Maps a JavaBean property to XML infoset representation and/or JAXB
>   element.

This means any known bean type (annotated with `@XmlRootElement`) which is passed into `setPayload`() will be resolved by the JAXB to their corresponding type, here that bean is `SmallBox`, otherwise to a default element type ( i think it should be the default implementation of `org.w3c.dom.Element`). After this change it will marshall the `JaxbAnnotationsTest` nicely to following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxbAnnotationsTest>
    <age>34</age>
    <id>100</id>
    <name>Brion</name>
    <payloadContainer>
        <small-box>
            <name>org.mycode.SmallBox</name>
            <type>SmallBox</type>
            <msg>I'm a small box</msg>
        </small-box>
    </payloadContainer>
</jaxbAnnotationsTest>
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it does not marshall the objects any differently.  I am using the Jackson 2 JAXB library to do both JSON and XML marshalling.  What are you using to get this sample code to produce your output?

Comment: Oh.. You could have mentioned that :) i haven't used any library I tried using JAXB standard JDK implementation. It works fine in both JDK 6 & 7

Comment: Interesting. I will try the embedded JAXB implementation and EclipseLink MOXy because I know Jackson does not fully implement the JAXB specification. Thank you!

Comment: I had to do a little more:  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) and then on Payload also use @XmlSeeAlso({SmallBox.class})